# .Net Core DbContext Threading issues from Blazor Server side

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, blazor-server-side, dbcontext

I am facing threading issues from a Blazor server side .NET Core project.

The `DbContext` definition looks like below:

```cs
 public class ADPortalDbContext:DbContext
 {
       public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

       public ADPortalDbContext(DbContextOptions<ADPortalDbContext> options)
          : base(options) { }
 }
```

The `Service` for returning the results from database looks like below:

```cs
public class CompanyService : ICompanyService
{
    private readonly ADPortalDbContext context;

    public CompanyService(ADPortalDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Company>> GetCompaniesSearchText(string searchText)
    {
        try
        {
            return await context.Companies
                .Where(i => EF.Functions.Like(i.Name.ToLower(), $"%{searchText.ToLower()}%"))
                .ToListAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to return results " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The exception is hitting at `GetCompaniesSearchText` method when i call the same function multiple times The error message is like below [ This function is getting called to populate the results of an auto complete dropdown and user can keep on typing chars inside dropdown this will keep  on getting executed and randomly ended up as exception ]

> Unable to return results A second operation was started on this
> context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused
> by different threads concurrently using the same instance of
> DbContext.For more information on how to avoid threading issues with
> DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.

Startup.cs of Blazor app is like below:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<ADPortalDbContext>(options =>
                        options.UseMySql(connStr, srvVersion, x =>
                        {
                            x.MigrationsAssembly("DCPortal.Infrastructre");
                        }),
                        contextLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

The Blazor page calling the service is like below:

```
@inject ICompanyService  CompanyService

/// <summary>
/// Autocomplete search handler
/// Returns the matched companies for the given search text
/// </summary>
/// <param name="searchText"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private async Task<IEnumerable<Company>> SearchCompanies(string searchText)
{
    try
    {
        IEnumerable<Company> companies_ListDb = await CompanyService.GetCompaniesSearchText(searchText);
        List<Company> CompaniesList = companies_ListDb.ToList();
        return companies_ListDb;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<Company>();
    }
}
```

It looks like the async await calls are placed in all necessary sections but not sure i missed something or did something wrong with combinations of `async` `await` and  `ConfigureAwait(false);`.

Comment: And how `CompanyService` is registered?

Comment: services.AddTransient<ICompanyService, CompanyService>(); Just edited the question

Comment: You can’t use AddDbContext in blazor. Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-6.0#database-access

Answer (score 0):

Blazor server side has issues due to the lifecycle and disposing of components when it comes to registering and using dbContexts. To put it very simply - transient context is not really transient in this case.
Simplest solution is to inject a dbContextFactory instead and create new context for each request - dbContext is a very lightweight object, so no issues there.

I used code below to register factory and also standard dbContext:

```
var sqlConfiguration = new Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder>(options =>
    {
        if (isDevelopment)
            options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();

        options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString(DbConnectionStringName),
            sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
            {
                    sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                    maxRetryCount: 5,
                    maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                    errorNumbersToAdd: null);
            });   
    });
    services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(options => sqlConfiguration(options));          
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => sqlConfiguration(options), optionsLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

After doing so in configure services portion of your code
just inject `IDbContextFactory` into your component. Just remember that you have to manually dispose contexts created by this factory (dispose by `.Dispose` or just use `Using` keyword when handling such context.)

Comment: But i am trying to load results from a service

Comment: Similar issue - lifespan of injected service reacts in the same way due to component lifetimes. In my case, when using mediatr to get / post  data from a service, I just refactored command hadlers to use context factory. I think, that if possible, that would be the simplest way. Each request done by a service would just need to use new context from factory. Otherwise due to scope handling by blazor component - the service will not be renewed -> context will not be renewed -> boom...

Comment: In other words - using dbContexts in components directly or by proxy is not very "clean" unfortunately.
Alternative would be to create new scope for each, lets say, button press and resolving this service as a new one. Depending on performance, it could be usable. There is also some methods involving `OwningComponentBase` or similar - to be honest, I do not remember it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @quain is correct in pointing you at the `IDBContextFactory`.  Blazor in inherently asynchronous, so trying to use a single DBContext for all your Database activity won't fly for long.

However, your code raises a couple of points:

1. You should never use services that use unmanaged resources (such as a DbContext) as transient.  Even if you implement `Dispose`, they will not be disposed until the SPA session ends.  You will create a memory leak, and use up resources.

This MSDocs article provides information on `IDbContextFactory` -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor.

2. If you wish to match the lifespan of your services with your pages/forms/components [good practice], this article (of mine) provides a discussion on how to do so, and solve the transient disposal issue.  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5352916/Matching-Services-with-the-Blazor-Component-Scope